# Describe the point or set of points that a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has in common with another line

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

Describe the point or set of points that the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with equation $wx + 3y - z = 2$ has in common with the line having the given parameterization $(x,y,z) = t(1,1,5) + (0,0,-2)$

I need help understanding the problem. I think that I need to find points $(x,y,z)$ such that they are solutions for both of the equation of the lines shown. The problem I am at is I think I need to convert both of the lines to one form or the other (both of them parametric, or both of them to be equation of lines format). Is that the right way to approach the problem? If so, what steps would I have to take to do that?

Comment: Note:  $(0,0,-2)$ is in the plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the equations in the forms given.

Points on the line have the form $(x,y,z)=t(1,1,5)+(0,0,-2)= (t,t,5t-2)$.

A point $(x,y,z)$ is in the plane if $wx+3y-z=2$.

So a point is on the line and in the plane if $wt+3t-(5t-2)=2$;

i.e., $wt-2t=0;$ i.e., $w=2$ or $t=0$.

When $w=2$, all of the points on the line are in the plane.

Otherwise, only the point when $t=0$ [i.e., $(0,0,-2)$] is on the line and in the plane.

Comment: Okay, so with the parametric line we are given, we can similarly check whether a point on the parametric line is on different planes by providing a different plane equations too?

Comment: Yes, this approach should work for any plane equation; note that it's possible for a plane and line in $\Bbb R^3$ to share no points

Comment: The plane and line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ should share no points when there is no solution for the plane equation with the given parametric line equation?

Comment: Yes; an easy example of that is the plane $z=1$ and the line $(0,0,0)+t(1,0,0)$